# reCAPTCHA Maihide: where is it?

Tags: recaptcha

With the last reCAPTCHA update, the function to hide mails ("Mailhide") seems to have vanished completely.

although you can still [get keys](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey) and although, actually, using the old libraries (no longer available from the website...) everything works.

Do someone know something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Google stopped reCAPTCHA Mailhide.
There was an alternative [scr.im](http://scr.im) but the website disappeared.

I'm now using [spamty](https://spamty.eu) which seems to work fine.